# Android: Sharing downloaded files

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider

I'm working on a feature where my app will download files from a server, then allow the user to open those files in external 3rd party apps (assuming the user has apps installed which can view the file types).

Files are downloaded and stored as byte arrays with some accompanying metadata which includes the MIME type and file extension.

A custom `ContentProvider` seems like the obvious way to go, since my app needs to retain control over the downloaded files - i.e. access by other apps should be read-only, and my app should control if/when the files are deleted.

When it comes to implementing my custom `ContentProvider`, I'm unclear on a few things. The tutorials I've looked at only seemed to be concerned with sharing data between two

1. Is it enough to just override and implement `openFile()` and implement `query()`, `insert()`, etc. as 'do nothing' stub methods?
2. Assuming that implementing `openFile()` is the way to go, how can I approach creating a `ParcelFileDescriptor` from a byte array?

Note: If at all possible I need to support all the way back to API level 3 (Cupcake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more digging around, and finally came across [this source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/src/com/android/email/provider/AttachmentProvider.java) for the Open Android `AttachmentProvider` implementation (for their email client).

So, to answer my own questions:

1. It looks like I need to implement `openFile()`, `getType()` and `query()`. Their `query()` implementation provides access to columns for display name, uri, filesize, and the '_ID' column ([as recommended by the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults)).
2. `ParcelFileDescriptor`s are specifically designed to work with `File`s (I guess the clue's in the name!) so the only way to do it is to write the byte array to the filesystem, then create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` for that `File`. Fortunately, it seems I can write to the app's private folder to prevent other apps messing with my files.

Comment: Another possibility may be to use MemoryFile. I'm working on this solution now, hopefully the performance is faster than regular files.

Comment: Regarding my comment above, I tried using MemoryFile in a content provider openFile() implementation but did not succeed. One reason is that support for ParcelFileDescriptor related to MemoryFile has been disappearing in recent Android versions. Even before that it required reflection tricks to access.

Comment: Is there any way to pass byte array to `ParcelFileDescriptor`? For security reasons, I can't save PDF file on the phone.